# Custom Tumblr Theme Pagination not working

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm working on my first custom Tumblr theme, and the pagination isn't working correctly. I have the links for "Next" and "Previous" set to go to {NextPage} and {PreviousPage} instead of URLs, but they only link right back to the same page they're on instead of going backward or forward. My html looks like this:

```html
{block:Pagination}
        <p id="pagination">
            {block:PreviousPage}
                <a href="{PreviousPage}">&larr;</a>
            {/block:PreviousPage}
            Page {CurrentPage}/{TotalPageCount}
            {block:NextPage}
                <a href="{NextPage}">&rarr;</a>
            {/block:NextPage}
        </p>
        {/block:Pagination}
```

CSS:

```css
      #pagination {
          font-size: 25px;
          color: silver;
          text-decoration: none;
          
      }
      #pagination a {
          font-size: 50px;
          text-decoration: none;
          margin-top: -20px;
      }
```

When I click on the links, they take me to the exact same page I'm clicking from (i.e. if I'm on the homepage, the link is the homepage; if I'm on page 5, they take me to page 5). Does anyone know why they're not linking correctly?

Comment: Live example? Where are you adding the `{block:Pagination}`?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is

```
{TotalPageCount}
```

should be

```
{TotalPages}
```

Although I don't suspect that would cause prev/next to output current page. Any other html or template tags interfering?